# Underline each line of text in paragraph left to right with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to animate underline each line of text in paragraph left to right with jQuery on button click, text will be entered dynamically. There is no new line(\n) in the text in paragraph.

How I approached it till yet is as following;

I am using regular expression to separate lines of text by character count not breaking any word, and wrapping it to span with class 'highlight', then in "span.highlight" I am inserting new empty span with 12 px height and width 0px. When I click button I animate width 0 to 100% and it looks like underline left to right.

The problem with this approach is this is not responsive. When window width is reduced the words breaks to new line and on animation those words are not underlined.

Please suggest solution.

Here is my code ;

```
$.fn.highlight = function(str) {
  var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
    }).replaceWith(function() {
      return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
        return "<span class='highlight'>" + match + "</span>";
      });
    });
  });
};
var text = '';
text = $('p').text();
var RExpress = /\S[\s\S]{0,105}\S(?=\s|$)/gi;
var splittedText;
var result = new Array();
while ((splittedText = RExpress.exec(text)) !== null) {
  $("p").highlight(splittedText[0]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code then.

Comment: please see the code above

Comment: Any luck with this ?